# object in mongo document is showing undefined in EJS

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

I am using this code to call data from MongoDB using mongoose npm. App is nodeJS, express and EJS based.

```
router.get('/getdata' ,(req, res) => {
  
    User.findOne({email: email2}).exec().then(user =>{
      if (user) {
        if (user.isEvent === "Yes"){
          Event.find().populate("creator").exec().then(events =>{
console.log(events[7].creator.name);
            res.render('viewfile', {
              userinfo: req.userinfo,
              events: events,
              user
            });
          })
        } else{
          console.log(user.isEvent);
          res.render('no-access', {
            userinfo: req.userinfo,
            user
          });
        }
        
      } else {
        
        res.render('noaccess', {
          userinfo: req.userinfo,
          user
        });
      }
    })
})
```

```
console.log(events[7].creator.name);
```

is showing expected result in the terminal but when I use this in EJS it says the name is not defined

```
<td><%= events[i].creator.name %></td>
```

Any advice on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

nevermind. I fixed it.
There were few events in the array that did not have any value in DB. Cleaning it up fixed it